# Connecting to AWS Managed Cassandra Service from Lagom

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, lagom, amazon-keyspaces

I'm having problems connecting to AWS Managed Cassandra Service from my Lagom environment. Here's what I have tried, with what results.

(1) Amazon provides instructions for connecting to AWS MCS from Java code:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/mcs/latest/devguide/cqlsh.html#using_java_driver

The gist of the instructions is that you need to install a certificate and then pass it to the JVM as follows:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path_to_file/cassandra_truststore.jks 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=amazon
```

Then, you can use any Cassandra Java drivers of your choice. And my choice is the DataStax drivers provided with the Lagom framework.

This I did by adding the following to `build.sbt`:

```
javaOptions ++= Seq(
  "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=project/cassandra_truststore.jks",
  "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=amazon"
)

// Must enable JVM forking to use javaOptions with runAll.
fork := true
```

(2) Before deploying my Lagom application to AWS, I want to work with it in Dev mode but connecting it to AWS MCS instead of the embedded Cassandra server. Lagom provides instructions for doing this in Dev mode:

https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/scala/CassandraServer.html#Connecting-to-a-locally-running-Cassandra-instance

The gist of the instructions is to add the following lines to `build.sbt`:

```
lagomCassandraEnabled in ThisBuild := false
lagomUnmanagedServices in ThisBuild := Map("cas_native" -> "tcp://localhost:9042")
```

The URI in this example assumes a Cassandra server running on `localhost:9042`. In my case, I substituted that with `cassandra.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9142`.

(3) Nevertheless, when I run `sbt runAll`, I'm getting timeouts when trying to reach AWS MCS:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: cassandra.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/3.83.168.143:9142 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [cassandra.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/3.83.168.143:9142] Operation timed out))
```

(4) I have isolated the problem by bypassing Lagom entirely and just writing a very simple piece of code, like this:

```
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "redacted_absolute_file_path/cassandra_truststore.jks")
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "amazon")

  val cluster = Cluster.builder.addContactPoint("cassandra.us-east-1.amazonaws.com").withPort(9142).build()
  val session = cluster.connect()
  session.close()
  cluster.close()
```

This is as simple as it gets. But the same timeout occurs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Was your AWS MCS' IAM policy updated to accept communications from your Lagom environment? If so, what port are you allowing the communication? looking at their documentation it seems that they use the custom port 4000, instead of Cassandra's default ports.

* I'm not a Lagom user, the answer is based on their documentation

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, it probably has to do with permissions. But the port is 9142, not 4000. Regardless, I have found this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_mcs.html. It doesn't say, thoughm, how those service-specific credentials are to be used.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution by looking at the AWS MCS Python documentation (the Java documentation is conspicuously silent on the matter). Turns out I do need to configure MCS service-specific credentials and then provide them in the Lagom's `application.conf` file as follows:

```
cassandra.default {
  port = 9142

  ssl.truststore {
    path = "path/cassandra_truststore.jks"
    password = "amazon"
  }

  authentication {
    username = "service-specific username"
    password = "service-specific password"
  }
}

cassandra-journal {
  port = ${cassandra.default.port}

  ssl.truststore {
    path = ${cassandra.default.ssl.truststore.path}
    password = ${cassandra.default.ssl.truststore.password}
  }

  authentication {
    username = ${cassandra.default.authentication.username}
    password = ${cassandra.default.authentication.password}
  }
}

cassandra-snapshot-store {
  port = ${cassandra.default.port}

  ssl.truststore {
    path = ${cassandra.default.ssl.truststore.path}
    password = ${cassandra.default.ssl.truststore.password}
  }

  authentication {
    username = ${cassandra.default.authentication.username}
    password = ${cassandra.default.authentication.password}
  }
}

lagom.persistence.read-side.cassandra {
  port = ${cassandra.default.port}

  ssl.truststore {
    path = ${cassandra.default.ssl.truststore.path}
    password = ${cassandra.default.ssl.truststore.password}
  }

  authentication {
    username = ${cassandra.default.authentication.username}
    password = ${cassandra.default.authentication.password}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! You saved me hours of headache.